# State does not update when expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I use filtering by category and text. Before every filtering by text I want to filter (reset) category, that is currently selected. **When text changes, the category is not updated in this case.** Do you have any idea why this happens? Thanks.

```
    handleSearchFilter = (searchText: string) => {
    const { selectedOption } = this.props;
    const { currentlyDisplayed } = this.state;

    this.handleSelectFilter(selectedOption);
    const newDisplayed = filter(currentlyDisplayed, (symbol: any) => symbol.name.cs.includes(searchText.toLowerCase()));
    this.setState({ currentlyDisplayed: newDisplayed });
};

handleSelectFilter = (selectedOption: string) => {
    const { symbols } = this.props;

    if (selectedOption === 'all') {
        this.setState({ currentlyDisplayed: symbols });
    } else {
        const newDisplayed = filter(symbols, (symbol: any) => symbol.category.includes(selectedOption.toLowerCase()));
        this.setState({ currentlyDisplayed: newDisplayed });
    }
};
```

Comment: this.setState({ currentlyDisplayed: newDisplayed }, () => console.log('state changed'));
console logs are fired, but state is not changed..

Comment: @mosses, where are your checking for updated state

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri everytime a character is typed (searchText), it should reset the category -> I should always filter by text the selected category. What happens now is that every time the list (currentlyDisplayed) gets shorter by typing, it doesnt reset its value when characters are removed.

Comment: @mosses, it happens that way because of a bug in your code wherein your are not saving the original data anywhere, rather filtering on the previously filtered result

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri original data is the symbols prop, which comes from redux store

Comment: Without the full code or at least a codesandbox, it is harder to help you. But I'd say you could try to have all your `this.setState` calls in the same function. I'm not sure why you're calling `this.handleSelectFilter(selectedOption);` on `handleSearchFilter`, but I'm pretty sure it's behaving differently than what you expect.

Comment: @ThiagoMurakami please see my comment to ShubhamKhatri answer. Do you think that the flow is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want by making a third function that returns `newDislayed` such as:

```
handleSearchFilter = (searchText: string) => {
    const { selectedOption } = this.props;
    const newDisplayed = this.getNewDisplayed(selectedOption, searchText);
    this.setState({ currentlyDisplayed: newDisplayed });
};

handleSelectFilter = (selectedOption: string) => {
    const newDisplayed = this.getNewDisplayed(selectedOption);
    this.setState({ currentlyDisplayed: newDisplayed });    
};

getNewDisplayed = (selectedOption: string, searchText = '') => {
    const { symbols } = this.props;
    if (selectedOption === 'all') {
        return symbols;
    } else {
        return filter(symbols, (symbol: any) => symbol.category.includes(selectedOption.toLowerCase()) && symbol.name.cs.includes(searchText.toLowerCase()) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand really well your filtering code but I'm pretty sure that your not expected behavior is because you are trying to modify the state 2 times in the `handleSearchFilter` method:

1. this.handleSelectFilter(selectedOption); // That produce a change on currentlyDisplayed
2. last line: this.setState({ currentlyDisplayed: newDisplayed });

I advise you to take a look of the reactjs doc (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)
Basically, `setState`is an Asynchronous method so you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state. What is happing its exactly that. Your first call ( this.handleSelectFilter(selectedOption); ) should be executing after the second one and overriding the result: `currentlyDisplayed`
I hope that can help you. If you explain me better your idea of filtering and workflow I could help you with the code fix.